# Error "Failed to launch test "

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I try launching cocos2d project and this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="farzadmo.farzad"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>

<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="farzadmo.farzad"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />




    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon">


     <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />

        <activity android:name="org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:configChanges="orientation">


            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                       android:value="cocos2dcpp" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
                      android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

at the first i got error and i solve them with this codes

```
<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="farzadmo.farzad"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

and

```
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```

now it's fixed, AVD launched and app install but now i got this "Warning: No instrumentation runner found for the launch, using android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" and this error "Failed to launch test" on Eclipse and app stopped on AVD.